# How to show the total number of properties that fit a client's criteria?

Tags: sql, xampp

My property table has propertyNo, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, OwnerNo, staffNo, and branchNo columns
While my Client table has clientNo, fname, lame, tellNo, prefType, and maxrent columns

```
SELECT client.ClientNo, propertyforrent.PropertyNo,client.prefType, fname
FROM client INNER JOIN
     propertyforrent
     ON propertyforrent.type = client.prefType
```

I tried this but it's not returning a sum of all the properties that match the client's prefType

Comment: Hint:  `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshoot with Left Join**

The `LEFT JOIN` will show you at minimal the clients and if a property matches the associated record.

```
SELECT 
    x.ClientNo
  , y.PropertyNo
  , x.prefType
  , fname
FROM client x
LEFT JOIN propertyforrent y ON y.type = x.prefType
```

**Using Group By and Count**

After you have worked out any bugs in the query, switch to `join`:

```
SELECT 
    x.ClientNo
  , x.prefType
  , COUNT(y.type) AS num_matches
FROM client x
JOIN propertyforrent y ON y.type = x.prefType
GROUP BY 
    x.ClientNo
  , x.prefType
```